# pushviewController/popviewController animation duration

Tags: iphone

When I push or pop a UIViewController, how long does the animation takes to complete the slide animation. I have a view on the main window, which I need to slide in sync when a ViewController is pushed or popped.

Does anyone has any idea on the type and duration of animation that takes place when I push or pop a view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great if there were a programmatic way of retrieving this value...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost all animations in the iPhone are 0.3 seconds.

Comment: btw.. as per my testing pop animation takes 0.35 seconds!

Answer (score 6):

In **iOS 7** and later you can have exact value by setting the `UINavigationController` delegate and using the method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSTimeInterval duration = [viewController.transitionCoordinator transitionDuration];
}
```

This is future proof method if the defult duration will ever change. At the moment it's value is 0.35 second.

Answer (score 4):

open the simulator and switch to slow animation, i found the push animation duration is 0.35f second

Answer (score 2):

The duration between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` is 0.35s on iOS 6 and before. After iOS 7 it's 0.505s.